# Add Property from action to an attachment of a story in open graphs

Tags: javascript, facebook

I want to add a property from an action to the Caption. The problem is that I don't know what's the correct nomenclature for that and I can't find it in the facebook documentation. I'm pretty sure it is possible since in the helper of the caption it says this "Can read properties from actions or objects and supports custom formatting.".

[image]

Anyone knows how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance,
Hoijof.

Comment: Start typing into the field, when you enter a curly brace `{` it will popup a list of properties to chose from. Continue typing the name of your action or object, and more specific results should show up.

Comment: @CBroe Wow, that's quite simple, why can't they document this things? Could you please put it as an answer? So I can close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start typing into the field, when you enter a curly brace `{` it will popup a list of properties to chose from. Continue typing the name of your action or object, and more specific results will show up.

(I don’t know if this is currently documented somewhere – all I can find right now is https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/custom#configure, but this doesn’t mention the “type-ahead” feature in place, or that the placeholder syntax uses curly braces. I think it was mentioned somewhere at some point, but might have gotten lost somehow during the constant re-structuring of FB documentation …)